# XSLT grouping trouble

Tags: xslt, grouping

I'm struggling with making the jump from iterative programming to XSLT. I asked one question before on here and it helped quite a bit, but now I'm back for another.

I'm trying to generate an order import file for a system using XSLT 1.0. I need to do some logic, and to simplify it down I came up with the example source data below

```
<orders>
  <order>
     <id>1</id>
     <items>
       <item>
          <sku>12345</sku>
          <addon></addon>
       </item>
       <item>
          <sku>23456</sku>
          <addon>A</addon>
       </item>
       <item>
          <sku>34567</sku>
          <addon>B</addon>
       </item>
     </items>
  </order>
  <order>
     <id>2</id>
     <items>
       <item>
          <sku>12345</sku>
          <addon></addon>
       </item>
       <item>
          <sku>23456</sku>
          <addon></addon>
       </item>
     </items>
  </order>
</orders>
```

Then for the output I just want to see the order ID and "Yes" or "No", depending on whether or not any items contained in that order have a value defined for addon. I don't care what that value is, but if it's anything besides blank for any item I want the output to be yes, and if all items are blank for addon then the output should show no for that order. For the above sample data, the output should be simply

```
1 Yes
2 No
```

First guess at something was

```
<xsl:key name="opt" match="item/addon" use="concat(ancestor::orders/order/id, '|', .)" />

<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:for-each select="orders/order">
      <xsl:value-of select="id" />
      <xsl:for-each select="orders/order/item/addon[count(. | key('opt', concat(orders/order/id), '|', .))[1]) = 1]">
         <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test=".=''"><xsl:text>Yes</xsl:text></xsl:when>          
            <xsl:otherwise><xsl:text>No</xsl:text></xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>   
</xsl:template>
```

I'll admit that I don't fully understand the syntax in the key and it's more copy/paste than anything I could have came up with myself. Looking at my attempt above though, I would think that this would output Yes twice because addon would have different values on items in order #1.

If I were doing this in a programming language that I understand, I'd use something like this pseudocode

```
bool hasAddon = false;
foreach(item in items)
{
    if(item.addon != "")
    {
       hasAddon = true;
       break;
    }
}
if(hasAddon)
   output Yes
else
   output No
```

That's where I'm struggling to translate the pseudocode into something usable in XSLT since I know for-each isn't quite the same in XSLT, you can't break a for-each, and you can only set a variable's value once. Without those options I'm feeling lost, and having problems understanding keys and recursive templates enough to potentially find a solution on my own. Any help would be awesome

Comment: Your items are already grouped. You only need to ask if the group contains an item that meets the criteria. No looping or recursion is required for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand what you need the key for, you can simply check `<xsl:choose><xsl:when test="items/item/addon[normalize-space()]">Yes</xsl:when><xsl:otherwise>No</xsl:otherwise></xsl:choose>`. inside of the `<xsl:for-each select="orders/order">`.

Comment: I assumed I would need to group my items and that addon so I didn't have it reporting multiple times based on various values that can be in that field. Like I said, total amateur here. Can you explain what the item/addon[normalize-space()] is referring to? Not questioning it, but I'd like to understand what that is doing. If that's all I need to do in order to do a generic check for values in a given field, then yes, that should work great.

Comment: @DanielHaley, thanks for the correction, I have edited the code snippet.

Comment: Inside the `<xsl:for-each select="orders/order">`, the `order` element is the context node and then the `<xsl:when test="items/item/addon[normalize-space()]">` (with the correction pointed out by Daniel Haley) checks there is an `addon` descendant with a text content other than white space so it checks with a single expression what you wanted to do with a loop in your imperative approach. With XPath an expression selecting nodes, when used in a boolean context like an `xsl:if/when test` evaluates to true if at least one node is selected by the path and to false if the selected nodeset is empty

Comment: Simple enough. Thank you very much for your help